# Know that iPhone is fully charged

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

How can I know that the iPhone is fully charged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIDevice` has a battery level property. Note, however, that you have to enable battery monitoring first, otherwise you'll always get `UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown`.

Comment: Thanks again, I've found how to enable the monitoring [[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];